# have any one faced this issue that mac terminal showing error in packages not pip?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyter notebook using pip3 install jupyter command but it failed so I installed jupyter by using brew as brew install jupyter and I can run jupyternotebbok from the local server but I can't run the jupyter in vs code. I am pasting the screenshot images if anyone may help?

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX9WE.png)

Comment: Please post your textual information as text, not as a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this error down:

```
psutil/_psutil_osx.c:35:10: note: did not find header 'ps/IOPowerSources.h' in framework 'IOkit' (loaded from '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks')
```

The process is trying to build [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#files) as a dependency and failing because there is a missing header file belonging to [IOkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit).

Possible solutions:

1. Update/Fix the install of IOkit, and try the build again.
2. Manually install a prebuilt wheel of psutil from pypi to avoid the build step and satisfy the dependency.